# What is elegant way to run all methods and return combined boolean result

Tags: delphi, boolean, return-value

I have method:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomething(param: String): Boolean;
```

Lets say this method is used often in one method, e.g.:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
begin
  DoSomething('one');
  DoSomething('two');
  DoSomething('three');
end;
```

If at least one `DoSomething` method returns `False` the result of whole method should be `False` too, while all methods calls should do their work.

Now I have this:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
var
  r1, r2, r3: Boolean;
begin
  r1 := DoSomething('one');
  r2 := DoSomething('two');
  r3 := DoSomething('three');
  Result := r1 and r2 and r3;
end;
```

which is just ugly. I can't inline `DoSomething` calls, 'cause if first method return `False` none of the rest methods will be called due to optimizations. I think I'm missing some simple and elegant way of doing this which I can't come up with.

Comment: Your existing solution is perfectly fine, but I'd add a comment to explain why it must not be changed. However, function with side effects are dangerous. Perhaps you need to reconsider the design at a more fundamental level. The fact that you are needing to do this at all is indicative of deeper problems.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is only example showing some issues in old code I'm maintaining now. Unfortunately redesigning is a cost which I can't afford now, so I have to play the game as it is.

Comment: So write it as you have it, add a comment, and move on. It's strange that you are concerned with elegance on legacy code. If you aren't able to actually change it to impose elegance, what is your concern?

Comment: I don't think it's strange. I just don't think that legacy code should be an excuse for me to write bad code.

Comment: What you have in the question is not bad code. It is by some distance the best code if you cannot avoid functions with side effects. What you have there is clear and explicit. You want the code to be verbose and look odd, with a comment, so that future readers will appreciate the issue. If you try to hide it with tricks as shown in the answers then you are obfuscating. Also, the question is clearly opinion based and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the safer and easiest pattern may be the following:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
begin
  result := DoSomething('one');
  if not DoSomething('two') then
    result := false;
  if not DoSomething('three') then
    result := false;
end;
```

It is clear to read and understand.

Other methods is based of current boolean expression evaluation settings, and are therefore more error prone.

Also consider returning an enumerate instead of a plain `boolean`, which may make the code logic more explicit: is `false` an error? better return `dsFailed` with a `TDoSomeThingResult = (dsSuccess, dsFailed)`.

Comment: I will go with this instead of @michael-vincent 's (which is also very good). + for this one is that it works with any version of Delphi.

Comment: This is far uglier than the code in the question!

Comment: Why? Its universal, straightforward, safe, no extra variables involved. Any arguments against?

Comment: It's opaque and ugly. Variables are good. Why don't you like variables? Anyway, this question is 100% opinion based and so should be closed. Not appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you want opinions go to the Delphi Devs group on Google+.

Comment: @David: In my opinion, you are right. <g> Alternatively, you can even find much more opinion in the Embarcadero groups/forums.

Answer (score 2):

How about passing the different parameters in a list?  Something like:

```
function DoSomethingManyTimes(const AList: array of String);
var
  ss: string;
begin
  result := true;
  for ss in AList do begin
    result := DoSomething(ss) and result;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nice, but is line `result := result and DoSomething(ss);` going to call `DoSomething` when previous calls set `result` to `False`?

Comment: @Vix with 'result := DoSomething(ss) and result;' it should work exactly as needed (Yoda-style)

Comment: @Vix, it isn't, but you can save the result in a local variable and use that in `Result and ...`.

Comment: I corrected this to defeat short circuit evaluation

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan - clumsy of me.

Comment: What has TObjectList<String> to do here? It won't even compile, since String is not a class.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [complete Boolean expression evaluation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_(Delphi_compiler_directive))* before the code and then disable it afterwards:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
begin
  {$IFOPT B-}
    {$DEFINE BOOLEVALISOFF}
    {$BOOLEVAL ON}
  {$ENDIF}

  Result := DoSomething('one') and
            DoSomething('two') and
            DoSomething('three');

  {$IFDEF BOOLEVALISOFF}
    {$UNDEF BOOLEVALISOFF}
    {$BOOLEVAL OFF}
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

With the `BOOLEVAL` directive `ON`, the compiler will generate code which evaluates the result of each expression even though overall result is already known, thus all of the functions will be called.

(* This directive is called `Boolean short-circuit evaluation` in the documentation, which is rather confusing, as it works the opposite way).

Comment: If the code unit is already in `BOOLEVAL ON` this would break existing code... So I would not go into this direction.

Comment: @Arnaud: One could use `{$IFOPT B-}{$DEFINE BOOLEVALISOFF}{$ELSE}{$UNDEF BOOLEVALISOFF}{$ENDIF}` or similar and use that to restore the original state.

Comment: All that to avoid perfectly clear and unambiguous code as found in the question. Keep it simple!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez too bad there is no #pragma push/pop in Delphi, could be handy in lot of situations, including this one.

Comment: @David: I agree that the method used in the question is probably the best way to do this. But vix doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: Fwiw this looks like an almost perfect duplicate of Remy's deleted answer which got one downvote, while this one got at leasr two upvotes. That's weird.

Comment: @rudy look at the original version of remy's answer

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The OP asked for something "elegant", and this awful cascade of conditionals is far from elegant IMHO.

Comment: I guess "elegant" is a matter of opinion. The above is, IMO, not. The original way, in the question, using variables, is still the most elegant, IMO.

Comment: @YuriyAfanasenkov There are indeed [$push / $pop conditionals in FPC](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu63.html) which are very convenient, and are lacking under Delphi, for sure.

Answer (score -3):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this.

The easiest and clear way (based on my opinion) would be to use if statement with multiple conditions like so

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
begin
  if DoSomething('one') and
     DoSomething('two') and
     DoSomething('three') = true then Result := True
  else Result := False;
end;
```

You can also use similar approach when you need that results for certain parameters are true but for other are false like so:

```
function SomeClass.DoSomethingManyTimesForDifferentParams: Boolean;
begin
  if (DoSomething('one') = True) and
     (DoSomething('two') = True) and
     (DoSomething('three') = False) = True then Result := True
  else Result := False;
end;
```

In this example the overall function will result `True` only if first two calls to `DoSomething` would return `True` and the last call to do something would return `False`.
Just note to put each separate condition in its own brackets as it is necessary while it was not necessary in previous example.

If you have your parameters in some list you call your `DoSomething` methods from inside a loop and check the results like so

```
function DoSomethingManyTimes(const AList: array of String): Boolean;
var
  ss: string;
begin
  for ss in AList do begin
    result := DoSomething(ss);
    //Break the loop if the result previously called DoSomething is False
    //to avoid calling DoSomething for every input parameter.
    if Result = False then Break;
  end;
end;
```

The last approach using loop comes especially useful if you have large number or even dynamic number of parameters that you send to your `DoSomething` method. But it is limited by the fact that it expects `DoSomething` to return true for every parameter so you don't have ability for different combinations `True` and `False` results as in my second example.

Comment: Using "= True" on a fubction that already returns a Boolean is obsolete. And short-circuit boolean evaluation (the default) would stop evaluating as soon as the rest of the expression would not change the result, so there is no guarantee that all functions will be called. The method used in the original question is the simplest and most readable way to do this.

Comment: If Booleana = true then result := true else result := false makes no sense, as it is equivalent to result := booleana.

Comment: again an answer that misses the point namely short circuit evaluation. -1